# How to compare 2 images in android using opencv?

Tags: android, opencv

I am very new to android and openCV, I'M working on **"Android application: plant disease Analyzer"**.

**Below is my workflow**:

1.I have static plant diseases in my gallery
2.End-user can capture an plant disease and submit to my application.
3.I want to compare the processed image with my gallery(Diseases) to get the most **similar disease**
Can any one tell me What will be the best algorithm to use?,
I have been searching on google but no luck,I tried with
below code snippet, which I tried using **openCV** :

```
   BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap camerabitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cameraimage, 
         bmOptions);
     Bitmap galareybitmap = 
   BitmapFactory.decodeFile(galImage.getAbsolutePath(), bmOptions);
   private double imageProcessing(Bitmap cameraimage,Bitmap 
    galimagebitmap,String galimagename) throws IOException {
    Mat img1 = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(cameraimage, img1);
    Mat img2 = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(gallimagebitmap, img2);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    img1.convertTo(img1, CvType.CV_32F);
    img2.convertTo(img2, CvType.CV_32F);
    //Log.d("ImageComparator", "img1:"+img1.rows()+"x"+img1.cols()+" img2:"+img2.rows()+"x"+img2.cols());
    Mat hist1 = new Mat();
    Mat hist2 = new Mat();
    MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(180);
    MatOfInt channels = new MatOfInt(0);
    ArrayList<Mat> bgr_planes1= new ArrayList<Mat>();
    ArrayList<Mat> bgr_planes2= new ArrayList<Mat>();
    Core.split(img1, bgr_planes1);
    Core.split(img2, bgr_planes2);
    MatOfFloat histRanges = new MatOfFloat(0f, 256f);
    boolean accumulate = false;
    Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes1, channels, new Mat(), hist1, histSize, histRanges);
    Core.normalize(hist1, hist1, 0, hist1.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
    Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes2, channels, new Mat(), hist2, histSize, histRanges);
    Core.normalize(hist2, hist2, 0, hist2.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
    /  img1.convertTo(img1, CvType.CV_32F);
    //  img2.convertTo(img2, CvType.CV_32F);
    hist1.convertTo(hist1, CvType.CV_32F);
    hist2.convertTo(hist2, CvType.CV_32F);
    return Imgproc.compareHist(hist1, hist2,3);

}
```

**I tried with template matching also in opencv**

```
     int match_method=Imgproc.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED;
     Mat temp = Imgcodecs.imread(tempim,Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );
     Mat img = Imgcodecs.imread(sourceim,Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE 
     );
    Size sz = new Size(200, 200);
    Mat resizeimage = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(img, resizeimage, sz);
    Mat sourceimage = resizeimage;

    Mat resizeimage2 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(temp, resizeimage2, sz);
    Mat templateimage = resizeimage2;

    int result_cols = sourceimage.cols() - templateimage.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = sourceimage.rows() - templateimage.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(sourceimage,templateimage, result, match_method);
    //Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
    Imgproc.threshold(result, result,0.1,1,Imgproc.THRESH_TOZERO);

    Point matchLoc,maxLoc,minLoc;
    Core.MinMaxLocResult mmr;
    boolean iterate = true;
    double minlocvalue,maxlocvalue,minminvalue,maxmaxvalue;
    while(true){
        mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);
        if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
            matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
            minminvalue = mmr.minVal; // test
        } else {
            matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
            maxmaxvalue = mmr.minVal; // test
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "mmr.maxVal : "+mmr.maxVal);
        if(mmr.maxVal >=0.2)
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "imagemathed..");

            Imgproc.rectangle(sourceimage, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templateimage.cols(),
                    matchLoc.y + templateimage.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
            Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile, img);
            Mat image = Imgcodecs.imread(outFile);
            try {
                Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(image.cols(), image.rows(),  Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                Utils.matToBitmap(image, bm);
                System.out.println("MinVal "+bm);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "image not mathced..");
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But every time I'M not getting the proper output, fault images are coming in the output.Please help me out, AM I following right approach, If not can some one suggest me which approach i have to follow.

Comment: You need some machine learning algorithm which compares the images and returns the most similar photo as result. You can start from here with [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition). This is not something you can do by comparing the bytes of the images.

Comment: Machine learning is a bit over the top, but i would use Mini TensorFlow

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Is there any way to do using openCV?